# How do you hook up Dwolla or Stripe API to accept ACH deposits on website?

Tags: stripe-payments, dwolla

I am trying to hook up Dwolla or Stripe API to accept ACH deposits on my website and am having trouble going through the instructions on API connections.  What programming language do you need to be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has an [ACH guide](https://stripe.com/docs/ach) explaining what you need to do in order to process ACH payments.

You will need to write some frontend JavaScript code, as well as some backend code. The backend code can be in the language of your choice -- Stripe has official libraries for [Ruby](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby#stripe-ruby-bindings-), [Python](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python#stripe-python-bindings-), [PHP](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#stripe-php-bindings), [Java](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java#stripe-java-bindings-), [Node.js](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#stripe-nodejs-bindings-) and [Go](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go#go-stripe--), but you can use any language as long as it can communicate with Stripe's API (i.e. as long as you can send HTTPS requests and decode JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Jylaw38 - It depends a little on what you want to do with Dwolla. You can use the branded v1 APIs that will allow you to accept payment with a full or a direct account. Basically, that means someone can sign up for the first time and use Dwolla to pay with their bank.

The more popular route these days is to use the v2 API. The v2 API's are bank transfer API's that put you in a position to brand the experience however you want. You can learn a little more about those here - https://www.dwolla.com/bank-transfers

There are libraries available for both API's and developer support on each is available here - https://discuss.dwolla.com/c/api-support